# Difference between 几点 and 什么时候?

Tags: difference

Is it correct that 几点 is for asking specific time in oclock...while 什么时候  is more general and can be answered specifically in oclock or a period of time such as morning, noon, night ?

I often heard 现在几点. But, is 现在是什么时候 or 现在什么时候 can also be used ?

Can i also replace "你什么时候有空" with "你几点有空" ???

Would means a lot if you guys can help me out..thanksss

Comment: 什么时候？when？at what time? Since 点 can mean "o'clock" (hour in some languages) e.g.十二点十分,evidently 几点 when？ what time？would expect a more precise answer (involving "o'clock" )  Asking for the (exact) time: 几点钟了? What’s the time?; What time is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it correct that 几点 is for asking specific time in oclock?

"几点" = "what hour". It could be 10:04 or 10:24, so it is only specific for the 'hour', not the specific 'time (moment)'. You can just answer by stating the hour; However, people asking 几点 is actually wanting to know  "**what hour and minute** (the precise time)". We usually reply to this question with the precise time on the clock.

> while 什么时候 is more general and can be answered specifically in oclock or a period of time such as morning, noon, night ?

Yes.

"现在是什么时候" = "what time is it now", it can mean specific time on the clock. For example, "现在是 10:24" ; it can also be used generally to refer to a period of time such as morning, noon.

> Can i also replace "你什么时候有空" with "你几点有空" ???

No, "你什么时候有空" refers to "which day and what time" ; "你几点有空" doesn't ask what date it will be. You can only replace  "你什么时候有空" with "你几点有空" when the date in known

*It can refer to any specific moment. For example " 现在是**时候**回家了" (it is **time** to go home)*

*to specifically ask for the precise time on the clock, you can say "现在是什么钟数?" or "现在是几点钟? "*

Comment: So can 几点 answered by all : date, moment and oclock??                                                  When you say that i can only use "你几点有空" when the date in known..did you mean that i have to state the date in the questions like 你明天几点有空 or i can just use 你几点有空 as long as the listeners know the date??          And is 现在什么时候 without 是 is also correct for asking what time is now?? Thnkss:)@Tang Ho

Comment: You can ask "你明天几点有空" (what time tomorrow will you have free time" to get the exact time.); If you just say   "你几点有空?" you have to state the date of the event in the same sentence or in earlier sentence in the same dialogue . for example "我们明天去参加彼得的派对,  你几点有空?"

Comment: the verb 是 can be omitted in "现在是什么时候" because it is strongly implied ( note: 现在什么时候 has no verb)